# check if object is exception of any kind

Tags: php, laravel, exception

In my API, I have a custom exception called ApiException. I want to pass all my error messages and exceptions in my code to this custom exception to handle logging and response return. I was thinking something like this:

```php
class ApiException extends Exception
{
    public $data;
    public $status;

    public function __construct($data, $status = 400)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $output = $this->getOutput();
        return response()->json($output, $this->status);
    }

    private function getOutput()
    {
        if (is_object($this->data) && $this->data instanceof Exception) {
            return $this->getOutputException();
        } else if (is_string($this->data)) {
            return $this->getOutputString();
        } else {
            return ['message' => $this->defaultMessage()];
        }
    }

    private function getOutputException()
    {
        // log exception
        // send notification
        return ['message' => $this->data->getMessage()];
    }

    private function getOutputString()
    {
        return ['message' => $this->data];
    }

    private function defaultMessage()
    {
        return __('message.defaultErrorMessage');
    }

}
```

I might use it to return a simple string:

```php
$resource = Resource::find($id);
if (!$resource)
    throw new ApiException("resource not found!");
```

Or pass a general exception:

```php
try {
    Table::insert($data);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    throw new ApiException($exception);
}
```

Or any other exception:

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client\Client();
try {
    return $client->request('GET', "http://something");
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException\ClientException $e) {
    throw new ApiException($exception);
}
```

Here is where I have a problem: `is any kind of exception`.

```php
private function getOutput()
{
    if (is_object($this->data) && $this->data instanceof Exception) {
        return $this->getOutputException();
    }
}
```

How can I check if my object is an exception? I mean any kind of exception, not just general exception, like `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException\ClientException`.

Comment: What do you mean with "How can I check if my object is an exception? I mean any kind of exception, not just general exception"? 
Do you want to know if "this->data" is some kind of exception?  That's what your code does

Comment: @MadCatERZ SO AI has edited my code adding `$this->data instanceof Exception` instead of my original code which was `this->data is any kind of exception` as comment ... are you telling me   `$this->data instanceof Exception` would recognize if object is any type of exception  (custom/general/ .... ) ?

Comment: I undeleted and edited my original answer.

Comment: @hretic I would recommend to subclass ApiException (and all other exceptions you define in your application) from RuntimeException instead of Exception. See https://php.watch/articles/PHP-exception-hierarchy for the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All custom Exceptions extend \Exception. Try this:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($this->data);
if($reflection->isSubclassOf(Exception::class)) {
  //$this->data is a subclass of Exception
}
```

Or, as in you code

```
if( $this->data instanceof Exception) {
 echo "yes";
}
```